# Images do not show on Desktop, only mobile

Tags: html, css, permalinks

I have a website that has multiple retailer images showing, and these are affiliate links. The issue I have is when I view on a desktop, even with cleared cache, cookies, and other browsers, I can see all retailer images, however when I am speaking with users of my site, they can not see images on desktop only mobile.

The website is [www.yourshoppingcentre.co.uk](http://www.yourshoppingcentre.co.uk)

I have a used the same code through the site to make it easier to add more retailers in the future, and an example can be found here:

```
        <div class="card" style="border: None;  padding-top: 5px;">
            <div class="thumbnail center well well-small text-center">
                <!-- START ADVERTISER: Kelsey Media from awin.com -->
                <a rel="sponsored" href="https://www.awin1.com/cread.php?s=3105047&v=19854&q=433993&r=1052665" target="blank">
                <img src="images/advertisers/kelsey_media.jpg" >
                </a>
                <!-- END ADVERTISER: Kelsey Media from awin.com -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="thumbnail center well well-small text-center">
                            <!--  <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add to Favourites!</button> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

One user has shown me a console screenshot where it shows the images have CSS of Display: None !important;
However again when inspecting the site myself I do not see this CSS and have no concept of how they are seeing this.

So I am guess I am asking a couple of things here, is this issue replicable, and secondly, if so, how to solve, as it is affects a subset and not all users is my understanding.

Appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's blocked by your adblock probably.

You can see that in your inspect tool :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The images are being blocked by an ad blocker on desktop. If your users disable their ad blocker, the images will show on desktop.

To resolve this, you might consider changing the URL you're using for those images.

Specifically, it seems that uBlock Origin doesn't like `advertisers` being in the image url.